# Finding closed form of for loop to get big o

Tags: asymptotics

I came across this problem

```
for (int i = n; i > 1; i = i / 4) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
     F()
    }
}
```

and I need to find the closed form for how many times F() is called so I can get the big o of it. I'm pretty sure it is O(n*log(n)), but I want to find it using summations.

Right now I have $\sum_{i = n}^1 \sum_{j = 0}^n 1$, but that doesn't seem right at all since $i$ is being divided by 4 each iteration. I also noticed that if $n = 4^k$ then we can see how many times it runs at a certain points using $a_k = \frac{n}{4^k}$, but I'm not sure what to do with that.

Not really sure how to express in in a closed form because of that first loop, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Count it for $n=4^k$ then replace by $k=\log_4(n)$ to have a formula in $k$. This is how you will get something in $n\ln(n)$.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Thank you

Comment: Note that $\mathcal{O}(n\log(n))$ assumes that the function F being called inside of the nested for-loops takes a constant amount of time.